# Managed Package - Allow only application code, and few authorized users, to insert records of a custom object

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, validation, insert, authorization

We have a custom object in our core managed package (visibility is public). There are a bunch of other managed packages that work alongside the core managed package and have code to insert records of a particular custom object. Additionally, the core package also has code to create records of this object. This custom object is packaged with the core package.

We now have a requirement that application code (in the core package, as well as other packages) should continue to be able to insert records for that object as per the business logic, but manual insertion of these records SHOULD BE PREVENTED. This would involve even System Administrators of Subscribers. Manual insertion can be defined as any attempt to create a record which is not in line with any valid business process, so this can be using the SF Standard UI, Data Loader, Anonymous Apex, Query Grid via Developer Console, or Workbench, or anything else for that matter.

However, the subscribers should be able to authorize a small set of users to be able to manually create those records for certain reasons.

What would be your suggestions to build this?